# DNS over TLS - socket closed

Tags: java, android, ssl, dns

So my situation is that I'm proxying all of the users DNS requests on an Android device and either resolve them using a local database or forward them to some upstream DNS server. With some bigger interest in DNS over TLS lately I've tried implementing it following the [rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7858). 
As all of this is done on a mobile device I don't want to establish a new TLS connection for each proxied request (that'd sum up to about 6.7 kB) because the user might be on a mobile connection.
Long story short, the rfc states the following:

> [...] this document
> stipulates that successful negotiation of TLS indicates the
> willingness of both parties to keep idle DNS connections open,
> independent of timeouts or other recommendations for DNS over TCP
> without TLS

I use the following code to send test requests and evaluate the result (trimmed down for readability).:

```
private void tlsTest(){
    Socket s = establishConnection("1.1.1.1"); //Cloudflare in this example, reproducible for Quad9 as well
    DataInputStream in; //Created from the Socket
    DataOutputStream out; //Created from the Socket
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        byte[] data = dnsRequestTypeA("google.com");
        data = new DatagramPacket(data, 0, data.length, destination, 853).getData();
        out.writeShort(data.length);
        out.write(data);
        out.flush();
        int times = 0;
        while((message = readDNSMessage(in)) == null && ++times <= 10){
            Thread.sleep(200);
        }
        System.out.println("Response: " + message);
        Thread.sleep(2500);
    }
}

private DNSMessage readDNSMessage(DataInputStream in) throws IOException {
    byte[] lengthBytes = new byte[2];
    if(in.read(lengthBytes) < 0)return null;
    // Each DNS answer is preceded with an unsigned short giving the length of the packet
    int length = (lengthBytes[0]&0xFF) + ((lengthBytes[1] &0xFF) << 8);
    byte[] data = new byte[length];
    in.read(data);
    return new DNSMessage(data);
}

@NonNull
private Socket establishConnection(String host) throws IOException {
    Socket socket = getSocketFactory().createSocket(host, 853);
    socket.setKeepAlive(true);
    return socket;
}
```

The problem here is that the server seemingly closes the connection (indicated by a broken pipe thrown when trying to send a request [`ssl=0x7ebb528840: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe`]) when there has been no request for a short time (about 1-2 seconds in my tests). 
Does anyone have experience with that? Am I doing something wrong (maybe it has something do do with the OpenSSL implementation Android is using for TLS)? Obviously just spamming the server every second or so with dummy requests would work but would be a very hacky workaround.

Comment: You can't do anythng about a connection that has already been closed by the peer.

Comment: Yeah I know, I initially asked whether anyone experiences the same or whether I did something wrong. But I've since learned that dns-over-tls servers don't conform to the RFC regarding the keep-alive of the tls session and simply end it after one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time of debugging I couldn't come with any direct solution. I haven't used a tools like Wireshark at time of writing this to determine any faulty implementation but have resorted to a different way of handling this for now;

I simply keep the sockets alive for as long as possible (if sending a packet fails it is retried max. 5 times before throwing an Exception). Additionally I cached all queries but as this impacted performance / resource usage pretty hard I dropped it again.